# Initializing a lookup table in c++

Tags: c++

Since I cant seem to make the constructor for my conversion class static, I tried faking it but its giving me an error about unresolved externals:

```
struct FloatConversions {
    static std::array<float, 256> ByteLUT;

    struct Initializer {
        Initializer() {
            for (double i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                ByteLUT[i] = i / 255.0;
            }
        }
    };
    Initializer Init;

    static inline float ByteToFloat(int val) {
        return ByteLUT[val];
    }
    static inline uint8_t FloatToByte(float val) {
        return static_cast<uint8_t>(val * 255.0f);
    }
};
typedef FloatConversions FC;
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Is this premature optimization? Have you considered that the float operation may be faster to perform than a table lookup?

Comment: I did consider that and tested it, lookup table was ~40% faster.

Comment: `static std::array<float, 256> ByteLUT;` only declares the lookup table. You still have to define it outside the `class {}` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that does the job.

```
float ByteToFloat(int val)
{
    static const struct FloatConversions
    {
        std::array<float, 256> ByteLUT;

        FloatConversions()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                ByteLUT[i] = i / 255.0f;
            }
        }
    } conveter;

    return conveter.ByteLUT[val];
}
```